# Debug ProcessBuilder Process inside of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

So first, let me explain what I want to achieve.
I got web application(Let's call it MainApp) which is run by jBoss web container. And my MainApp is starting jar file as separate process via ProcessBuilder.

I read that I should use eclipse feature "Remote Java Application", but it seems that it is not working for me.

So let me tell you what steps I am following:

```
java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -jar secondApp.jar
```

- in my ProcessBuilder, I am setting my command line to above
  instruction
- in run->debug configuration I am setting new remote java application
  with host set to `localhost` and port set to `5005`.
- and than I am running MainApp in jBoss container from eclipse on port `8010`.
- and than I am not sure what should I do.

So let me add some notes to better understand my issue.
Inside of my WebApplication i got class with code like this:

```
    String commandLine = "java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -jar secondApp.jar";

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandLine);
    pb.run();
```

And it is working more or less like this: Deploy MainApp in jBoss, and when some action occure start new Process which starts secondApp.jar on server machine.

Comment: All sounds good.  Once `secondApp` has been started from jBoss it will wait with the `suspend=y`.  You should then be able to go back to the debug configuration for the new Remote Java Application, and launch it.  It will then try to connect on port 5005 as configured.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: @df778899 
I have expressed myself badly, first what I am running is MainApp/FirstApp which is responsible for invoking SecondApp.jar. So what I am doing is running only MainApp inside of jBoss and than I dont know what to do to be able to debug SecondApp.jar

Comment: That still sounds good.  Once SecondApp.jar is triggered, the `suspend=y` will cause it show a message like `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005` to standard out, and do nothing else until you connect from the Remote Java Application debug configuration back in Eclipse, also on port 5005.  But it does sound like something else isn't right.  If you're not already, it might be worth capturing or redirecting the output and error output from the `java ... secondApp.jar` process, see what that reveals.

Comment: What `ProcessBuilder` are you using? There is no method `run` in `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`. Where is `secondapp.jar` located? In JBoss' base directory?

Comment: So what is the problem, open your second app project and [connect for remote debugging](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help%2Fhtml%2Freference%2Fnode47.html) with your host and 5005 port